# two recyclerview in scrollview does not works properly

Tags: android-recyclerview, scrollview

As you know after support library 23.2 when you put recyclerview inside scrollview as wrap_content then the scroll events work properly by using `setnestedscrollviewenabled(false)`. But if there is a two recyclerview in a one scrollview then the second recycylerview does not wrap to its content size. Is there a way to achieve it?

Comment: Have a look at this implementation. https://github.com/comeondude/dynamic-recyclerview/wiki. The code is found here https://github.com/comeondude/dynamic-recyclerview

Comment: i solved my problem  by using NestedScrollView insted of ScrollView on the root element of layout for two recylerview in a scrollview. @ReazMurshed

Comment: I just suggested a better approach.

Comment: Thank you but in my method there is no need to use complicated things:) it works by writing just 2 line codes

Answer (score 0):

i solved it by using `NestedScrollView` insted of `ScrollView` on the root element of layout.